# How to build complex breadcrumbs

Tags: zend-framework

I need a little advice how to make Zend Framework breadcrumbs more complex than
**"Home page / controller / action".**

I want to use nested categories for displaying aricles in my blog module. So breadcrumbs should look like this:
**Home page / Blog / Category_1 / Category_1-1 / Category_1-1-1 / Post title**

Can someone give me a little briefing for this?

I can implement categories/subcategories by setting parent item ID for each blog post and iterate over all entries to build simple php array or use Composite pattern or do it in any other sugested way.

But i don't have any idea how to build that complex breadcrumbs. Can I plug-in in to the breadcrumbs generation process somehow?

Comment: You may should have a look at the [breadcrumb view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.navigation.breadcrumbs)

Comment: You should create navigation (build navigation tree)
Before you output categories' data, you should add the category to navigation, for example, $navigationContainer->findOneByLabel->addPage(array(
    'uri' => 'http://www.example.com/'
)))

Comment: So if I build my navigation tree dynamically using zend_navigation and add categories tree retrived from database like below:

**"Home page / Blog (<- controller) / Categories (<- action) / [category1|category2|category3|category4] (<- array of uris build from database)"**

Then my breadcrumbs will be generated "auto-magically"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use modified view placeholder - it supports varous dividers and it's easy to build by extending the view placeholder class.

```
echo $this->breadcrumbs()->append($title, $url)->append($title2, $url2);
```